# How do I resolve (non SDK) class dependancies when using QuickBlox sample code in my own project?

Tags: android, android-studio, quickblox

I am trying to figure out how to use the quickblox sample-chat code in my own Android Studio project.

What I want to do is have an initial screen of buttons (one of them is labelled "Chat"). When the user clicks the Chat button, that will kick off the Quickblox sample-chat code, starting with the SplashActivity.

I have created a new project, gotten the initial screen buttons in place (including the Chat button), imported the quickblox SDK and c908.stickerfactory library just fine.

The problem from here is that (because I am a newbie), I don't know the best way to bring the sample-chat code into my project. I've copied and pasted everything into my project piecemeal (class files, xml layout files, icons, etc.).

When building my project, I'm running into into missing dependancies that I cannot figure out how to include. For example, in my project, when examining NewDialogActivity.java (again, this has been copied over from sample-chat), the compiler cannot find these imports:

```
import com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshBase;
import com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView;
import com.quickblox.sample.chat.R;
import com.quickblox.sample.chat.core.ChatService;
import com.quickblox.sample.chat.ui.adapters.UsersAdapter;
```

In the sample-chat project, these exist as .class files starting at:

/sample-chat/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/...

So, here are my questions:

1. How do I get these class files into my project as dependancies? I've tried several things:

   - Copying the .class files into my lib folder (they can't be added as libraries).
   - Copying the classes directory (from the path above) into the /build/intermediates/ directory of my project (Android Studio just deletes the classes directory when I Clean the project).
   - Tried to find where in "Build->Edit Libraries and Dependancies" I can add the .class files (There is no way to do it).
2. Is there a better way to do what I'm attempting? I know others must be using this same pre-built quickblox sample-chat functionality. Is there a more elegant way to bring it into an existing project.

Don't forget I'm an Android and Quickblox newbie, so please go slow.

Many thanks for the help!